# Redirect Page when session timeout expires

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I want to re-direct the user to Home page when the session has expired during a post back.
When the form timeout occurs then user is directed to login page.

Session timeout = 20, Form timeout = 2880

I tried the following code in the Global.asax, but does not work and causes Application_Error ("Response is not available in this context.").

```
Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the session ends
    Response.Redirect("~/HomePage.aspx")
End Sub
```

Comment: @MajoB The error is "Response is not available in this context."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a property in your web.config

```
<forms name="WhateverYourAuthNameIs" 
       loginUrl="~/HomePage.aspx" 
       defaultUrl="~/Default.aspx" 
       protection="All" path="/" 
       cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
```

When the expiration occurs they will be sent to the page that `loginUrl` is set to.

Comment: I'd like to refresh or direct to HomePage.aspx on Session timeout and redirect to LoginPage.aspx on Form timeout. So i'm not sure this will handle issue.

Comment: I guess if I set Session timeout = 20 and form timeout = 20 then it will just redirect back to login. I just didn't want to have them re-log back in if the session variables dumped.

Comment: Exactly. You'll deal with a lot less problems that way.

Comment: I set each one to 300, started the web application and let it sit idle. After about 150 min it timed out and displayed the login page as expected. Is it possible that the server or browser timed out before my anticipated 300 min timeout?

Comment: If you increase the Session timeout then you have also have to increase the application idle timeout from the Application Pool. If the Session timeout is greater then the Application Pool's idle timeout, then the Session will be expire because the Application is recycled before session timeout.

Answer (score 2):

The Session_End is not initiated by the browser (because any response from the browser should in theory extend the Session by another 20 minutes), therefore the concept of a Response object doesn't make sense.

The only option I can see would be to have some sort of client side script (javascript) that utilises the `window.setTimeout` function... something like (untested)...

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(function(){document.location.href='/Home.aspx';},72000000);">
```

**UPDATE**

Having read the request again, the requirement is slightly ambiguous.  If the requirement is for the webpage to automatically redirect after the 20 minutes (without user intervention), then my answer addresses that.

However, I think it's more likely that the requirement is to redirect to the homepage if the user *sends another request to the server* after the 20 minutes.  In which case, MajoB's answer is a good one.

Comment: Your second statement is correct in your update. Thank you. I am going to try MajoB's approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you cant use  `Server.Transfer` or `Respose.Redirect` then you can check for some session variable in page_load event of each page. And if is this session variable is null then redirect to specific page. You can create base page to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @MagoB Thanks but I got the following error..."Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Depending on the scope of which pages you want this functionality, you could always use the Application_BeginRequest within Global.ascx.  Obviously check to see which page is being requested, and make sure it isn't HomePage.aspx, otherwise you'll end up in an infinite loop

Comment: I'm going to try the session variable method and see how that works. thanks

Comment: Although this also was a good answer i'm going to go with setting each timeout to be the same and just setup the form loginUrl in (web.config) back to the login page. Less problems. Thank you.